# Nginx SSL certificates path format

Tags: ssl, nginx, https

I'm a newbie with NGNIX and server configurations in general and I'm trying to implement SSL certificates in order to move a website to HTTPS protocol.

Nginx doc's instruct to add these lines to point to the certificate and private key files:

```
    ssl_certificate     www.example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key www.example.com.key;
```

Can these be in the format:

```
    www.example.com/crt
    www.example.com/key
```

Else, I'm not sure hoy to point an address like www.example.com.crt to a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` directives should point to files stored at a location on your disk, and not over the Internet.

E.g.,

```
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/mysite/chained.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/mysite/private.key;
```